# Is there a way to test two opposite methods in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have two opposite methods that I have to test

First method

```
private boolean isGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber(Character oldNdipAffectation,
      Character newNdipAffectation) {
    return isNdip09NatifVoipSip(newNdipAffectation)
        && isNdipGeoOperator(oldNdipAffectation);
}
```

Second method

```
private boolean isNonGeoSipOutboundPortabilityToGeoFiberOrt(Character oldNdipAffectation,
      Character newNdipAffectation) {
    return isNdipGeoOperator(newNdipAffectation)
        && isNdip09NatifVoipSip(oldNdipAffectation);
}
```

Here is the implementation

```
protected void checkRenumberingValidation(Character oldNdipAffectation,
      NdipRenumberingRequest request, String basicatCode) {
    var oldNdipIndicatif = findIndicatifByNd(request.getOldNdip());
    var newNdipIndicatif = findIndicatifByNd(request.getNewNdip());

    if (!isClassicIpPortedNds(request)
        || !isGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber(oldNdipAffectation, newNdipAffectation)
        || !isNonGeoSipOutboundPortabilityToGeoFiberOrt(oldNdipAffectation, newNdipAffectation)
        || !isRtcPortabilityToFiberSip(newNdipIndicatif, oldNdipAffectation, newNdipAffectation,
        basicatCode)
        && (
        !Objects.equals(newNdipIndicatif.getZne().getCzne(), oldNdipIndicatif.getZne().getCzne())
            || !Objects.equals(newNdipIndicatif.getCsitugeo(), oldNdipIndicatif.getCsitugeo()))
    ) {
      throwFunctionalException(ERROR_34);
    }

}
```

If I pass 'D' and 'P' this will cause throwFunctionalException(ERROR_34) and that is fine

```
!isGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber('D', 'P') // Throw exception which is expected
```

The problem is the `isRtcPortabilityToFiberSip()` method is never reached because if I pass 'P' and 'D'

```
!isGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber('P', 'D') // Pass
isNonGeoSipOutboundPortabilityToGeoFiberOrt('P', 'D') // Throw exception which is expected
!isRtcPortabilityToFiberSip(newNdipIndicatif, oldNdipAffectation, newNdipAffectation,
        basicatCode) // never reached
```

How to reach `!isRtcPortabilityToFiberSip` with JUnit 5?

I googled the problem without any solution.

Comment: Look at `assertThrows(...)` - you basically test for the exception and then let the test continue if it is thrown. You might also want to think about whether these 3 calls would actually be 3 independent tests - at least the first 2 seem to be since it doesn't make sense to fail _and_ pass on the same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to have three different test functions:

```java
    @Test
    public void testIsGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber() throws Exception
    {
        !isGeoOrtInboundPortabilityToNonGeoSipFiber('P', 'D') // Pass
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testIsNonGeoSipOutboundPortabilityToGeoFiberOrt() throws Exception
    {
        isNonGeoSipOutboundPortabilityToGeoFiberOrt('P', 'D') // Throw exception which is expected
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsRtcPortabilityToFiberSip() throws Exception
    {
        !isRtcPortabilityToFiberSip(newNdipIndicatif, oldNdipAffectation, newNdipAffectation,
        basicatCode) // never reached, but now it will be!
    }
```

A good practice is to have one assertion per test [(although this is flexible)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test)

Your code does not really have assertions (they could be added by having `checkRenumberingValidation` return a boolean value, instead of throwing an exception when objects are not equal), but the conditions are being checked adequately, just in a more roundabout way than usual.

---

For more reading about testing, I highly recommend the [JUnit FAQ](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html)
*(written when JUnit 4 was current, but nearly all concepts can be applied generally -- this is a classic)*